# best practices for placeing firewalls?

Tags: firewall

They are many places place firewalls, what are the most important places to set up a firewall. I know that its really important to set up a firewall at the router that leads the traffic from the outside into the private network, should we add some more firewalls in the private network or is it enough with one?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends. If you have any network which should be protected from any other network at your site, then you can use a firewall. For instance, many companies isolate labs from the other networks by placing a firewall to protect the production network from the lab network.

Comment: ok, so a firewall that checks the traffic from the outside network and maybe a firewall between the subnetwork with a network. Anymore every-day-cases where the firewall comes into play?

Comment: It's really pretty simple. Firewalls protect networks. If you have a network that you want to protect, then you use a firewall to protect it.

Answer (score 0):

External firewall like you mentioned is a must. If you have internet facing services such as website that you host from within your company servers or a DNS server etc then you create a DMZ. Which means there is a firewall between Internet connection and your Internet facing servers and then another firewall to protect your internal network.

Also you should ideally enable host based firewalls like the windows firewall as security threats are not only external but internal as well.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly depends on the architecture of the network. For example, if it's 3-legged, one right in front of the external router, one in front of DMZ, and one for private network.